# PHP commands and my file system don't work

Tags: php, command

I'm sorry about my bad english.

I have encountered this error after installing the lamp server with this code. Previously, my same file system was working properly.

Lamp Server İnstall Command: `"sudo tasksel install lamp-server"`

Config File : `define("URL", "http://localhost/test/");`
Code: `header("location:".URL."login");`
Result: `http://localhost/test/templates/URLlogin`

I have no idea what the source of the problem is. Although I searched the web, I couldn't get any results. Thank you in advance for your help.

Respects

Comment: Are you saying PHP worked, you installed a package, and now it doesn't work?

Comment: I need to go to "http://localhost/test/templates/login" when I type the header ("Location: login") and it goes to http://localhost/test/templates/URLlogin

Comment: Cannot be reproduced from this very sample code. (= Your issue lies elsewhere.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are getting URL printed instead of your constant, its because it is not defined in your current scope.

Is your config file being included or required at all anywhere? I would suggest it is not.

The default PHP behavior is to use the constant name as a string if it is not defined.

This would also trigger a warning in your logs.

Eg if you 
define('URL', 'your url); 
In one file, but do not have access/scope in another then using **URL** will give it to you as a string.
Eg 
header('Location: ' . URL);
Will try to header over to 'Location: URL' instead of 'Location: your url'